# how to control exceptin on "." when converting to string

Tags: java, string, netbeans, integer, calculator

I'm creating simple CAL.I'm a beginner to JAVA.
I got error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0."
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at javaapplication11.GUI.NewJFrame.jButton4ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:237)
    at javaapplication11.GUI.NewJFrame.access$400(NewJFrame.java:11)
    at javaapplication11.GUI.NewJFrame$5.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

code section

```
private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if(0==Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())){
        jTextField1.setText("0.");
    }
    else{
            String a=jTextField1.getText();
            jTextField1.setText(a+".");}
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting a period?

Answer (score 0):

It says

`at javaapplication11.GUI.NewJFrame.jButton4ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:237)`

Are you sure the code you are providing is the correct one? because your code says `jButton11ActionPerformed` instead of `jButton4ActionPerformed` as the error says.

Comment: this should be a comment instead of an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you know, that your last position is a dot, you can use substring to cut it.

```
String text = jTextField1.getText().substring(0, jTextField1.getText().length()-1); 
if(0==Integer.parseInt(text)) {...}
```